# Loop through list to copy batches of like values

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I'm trying to copy batches of rows, based upon one column's values.

The worksheet looks like this (sorted by the first column):

```
A  5  blue  
A  6  yellow  
B  3  red  
B  2  blue
```

The loop has 3 primary steps:

1. Copy all rows beginning with a value, e.g. rows 1-2, which both begin with "A"
2. Paste rows into an email (I know how to do this)
3. Move to the value, B, and copy all rows starting with B

I won't know the values of Column A, as they will change each time. Is there a way I can still write this loop?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you sending each batch to a seprate email address?  Otherwise why are you seperating by batch?

Answer (score 1):

2 possible approaches:

1: Rather than thinking of it as copying all the "A" rows at once, have a build string that you add to for each row, and then when you hit a new value for the first column, flush the build string into the email. That way its a single loop with a condition check in there.

2:

- Maintain a startPos. set it to 1.
- Loop through first col till value changes.
- Copy startRow - currentRow - 1 to email.
- set startPos = currentRow.
- Repeat.

Comment: Thank you Jon, those are great tips! I'll give those a shot.